# Chrome Extenstion(Js file) To Php Data Sending

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

So I am very new to chrome extensions and what i am trying to get done with my first chrome extension is to send a url from chrome extension to a php file.

I have tried `$.post` method and also `$.ajax` but the `isset` function in php to check post data always fails.

Here is my code:

- manifest.json

  ```
  {
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "First Chrome Extension",
    "description": "Send Url On Click",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "icon.png",
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "content_scripts": [
      {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-2.1.4.min.js"]
      }
    ],

    "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/", 
    "https://*/"
    ]
  }
  ```
- POPUP.html

  ```
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>First Chrome Extension</title>
      <script src="popup.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
              <form name="testform">
              <input type='button' id='alertButton' value='Send URL'>
              <div id="returnfromphp"></div>
              </form>
              <script  src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```
- POPUP.js

  ```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById('alertButton').addEventListener('click', ShowUrl);
  }); 


  function ShowUrl(){
      chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
      myfunction(tab.url);
  });

  }

  function myfunction(tablink) {
      var urlretained = tablink;
      alert(urlretained);

      $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "myfile.php",
              data: {myData:urlretained},
              success: function(data){
                  alert('Items added');
              },
              error: function(e){
                  console.log(e.message);
                  alert('Addition Failed');
              }
      });

  }
  ```
- myfile.php

  ```
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['myData'])){
          echo"Data Detected";
  }else{
          echo"Data Not Set";
  }
  ?>
  ```

Comment: You're sending the request to `url: "myfile.php"` without the full server url, why?

Comment: Because the file currently is in the same folder as my extention , but can i add the url using localhost because i dont have a live domain as of now , P.S Thanks for the edits , the question appears way better now !!

Comment: I think the url must be the standard `protocol://host:port/path` (`http://localhost/something/myfile.php`) because the request is sent via the network stack, not the file system.

Comment: Thanks a lot , that worked !!!!